# How to loop through columns of two dataframes, group by key & perform calculation

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes with around 300 columns which contain pre- and post- intervention scores. I need to calculate the difference between pre and post, in each column, for each participant who has a single ID. As a small example I have:

```
Pre-intervention:
     ID     DEPRESSION  ANXIETY COGNITION
0   001          10        2       6
1   002          15       12      -3
2   003          14       -2       6
3   004          14        1       2

Post-intervention:
     ID     DEPRESSION  ANXIETY COGNITION
0   001           9        3      10
1   002           6       -5       2
2   003          14        8      -3
3   004           2       11       2
```

I am using the below code (adapted from [Using two dataframes to calculate final value pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49059296/using-two-dataframes-to-calculate-final-value-pandas)), which creates a series mapping ID to the sum of DEPRESSION, then maps these summations to ID in df1 and subtracts from DEPRESSION.

```
s = df1.groupby('ID')['DEPRESSION'].sum()

df2['DEPRESSION'] = df2['DEPRESSION'] - df2['ID'].map(s).fillna(0)
```

Which gives me:

```
    ID  DEPRESSION  ANXIETY     COGNITION
0   001     -1         3           10
1   002     -9        -5            2
2   003      0         8           -3
3   004     -12       11            2
```

i.e. the difference in the depression column. I cannot work out how to apply this to every column in my dataframes. I have tried writing a for loop over column names but I'm struggling because of the `groupby` element (I think).

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you do?:

```
newdf = df2.sub(df1, fill_value=0) 
newdf['ID'] = df1['ID']
```

You can do it these two ways as well:

One by one

```
newdf['ID'] = df1['ID']
newdf['DEPRESSION'] = df2['DEPRESSION'] - df1['DEPRESSION'] 
newdf['ANXIETY'] = df2['ANXIETY'] - df1['ANXIETY']
newdf['COGNITION'] = df2['COGNITION'] - df1['COGNITION']
```

Or build the columns, drop them, with the sub. You can use ['col1', 'col2'] inside columns= but with your column names here instead of col1, col2:

```
df2.drop(columns=['col1', 'col2']).sub(df1.drop(columns=['col1', 'col2']))
```

I hope one of these helps

Comment: Yes that works! Can't believe I didn't know about .sub, so much more simple. It does mean I have to remove any columns containing strings prior to running, is there a way around this do you know?

Comment: I updated the answer, let me know if you need me to expand on any, thx! You might be able to do a regex column drop, idk, but i'm going to look into it on the side

Comment: Thank you very much. As I have around 300 columns in my actual df it's not feasible to use the second options, but the frst works as long as all of the columns contain numbers.